# Having trouble creating a SQlite database, no such column?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Let me start by saying, yes I have un-installed the app from my emulator each time I re-try it!!

Ok hopefully this one is pretty simple. I am learning android SQLITE and below is an extremely simple database in which I'm setting the text value default. Naturally one would think that by setting a column default then Sqlite should automatically insert a row right? regardless I keep getting the no such column as myColumn error. please help!

```
public class DatabaseTestHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    private static final String DB_NAME = "DB_NAME";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "CREATE TABLE SORT_TABLE (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
myColumn TEXT DEFAULT 'IT WORKED!!');";


 public DatabaseTestHelper(Context context){
    super(context,DB_NAME,null,DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
 }

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

}
```

this is an instantiated buttons onClick

```
 public void onClickYo(View view) {
    new AsyncTaskTest().execute(true);
}

here is the Async in the same class
  private class AsyncTaskTest extends AsyncTask<Boolean,Void,String>{
        String success;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Boolean... sortTests) {
            try {
                SQLiteOpenHelper dbHelper =
                        new DatabaseTestHelper(titleActivity.this);
                SQLiteDatabase theDb = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
                Cursor cursor = theDb.query(
                        "SORT_TABLE",new String[]{"myColumn"},
                        null,null,null,
                        null,null);

                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                     success = cursor.getString(0);
                } else {
                    success = "MOVE TO FIRST TRIPPIN";
                }

                cursor.close();
                theDb.close();

            } catch(SQLiteException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return success;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String dbString) {
            textView.setText(dbString);

        }
    }
}


09-05 18:32:31.935 10341-10387/com.hf.mysquad E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: myColumn
```

Comment: Can you post the query code that throws the error?

Comment: Ok i will update my question

Comment: You just posted the error log itself. Do you actually query the table you have created?

Comment: Lol yes, I just posted the code. Everytime I click my button the textView is blank and my stacktrace gives the error "myColumn" doesnt exist...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = 
         "CREATE TABLE SORT_TABLE (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,myColumn TEXT);";

  db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
```

In your ISSUE #2, there are five `"`, the number of double quote is odd, so its wrong.

and In your ISSUE#1, special single quote should be replaced with doulbe single quote,

```
' shoule be ''
```

The better way is to use a native Android method designed for exactly this purpose. [sqlEscapeString](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils#sqlEscapeString(java.lang.String))

Comment: I cleaned the code up a bit and edited my question. Sorry for removing your answer, but it didnt work.